# extending each row in a matrix by adding to the end?

Tags: python, matrix

I'm trying to increase the length of the rows in my matrix by appending 1 to the end of each line.

```
matrix_1 = [[-4, -2, -3],[-1, -1, 1],[-2, 0, 1]]
```

I need the output to be:

```
matrix_2 = [[-4,-2,-3,1],[-1,-1,1,1],[-2,0,1,1]]
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're doing heavy numerical work with this matrix, you will probably benefit from using numpy (basically *the* Python linear algbera library). If your matrix is a numpy array rather than nested lists, like so:

```
import numpy as np
matrix_1 = np.array([[-4, -2, -3],[-1, -1, 1],[-2, 0, 1]])
```

then you can expand it using numpy's [`hstack`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.hstack.html) function:

```
column_of_ones = np.ones((matrix_1.shape[0], 1))
matrix_2 = np.hstack((matrix_1, column_of_ones))
```

Answer (score 1):

```
matrix_1 = [[-4, -2, -3],[-1, -1, 1],[-2, 0, 1]]
for i in matrix_1:
    i.append(1)
```

## output

```
[[-4, -2, -3, 1], [-1, -1, 1, 1], [-2, 0, 1, 1]]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
matrix_1 = [[-4, -2, -3],[-1, -1, 1],[-2, 0, 1]]
def add_one(L, V):
    return [X + [V] for X in L]
print(add_one(matrix_1, 1))
```

The ouput is:

```
[[-4, -2, -3, 1], [-1, -1, 1, 1], [-2, 0, 1, 1]]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> [i + [1] for i in matrix_1]
[[-4, -2, -3, 1], [-1, -1, 1, 1], [-2, 0, 1, 1]]
```

And just for fun

```
>>> zip(*zip(*matrix_1) + [(1,) * 3])
[(-4, -2, -3, 1), (-1, -1, 1, 1), (-2, 0, 1, 1)]
```